# How can I copy personalization rules to a rendering in Sitecore Powershell?

Tags: presentation, powershell-extensions

I'm copying a rendering from one item to another using Sitecore Powershell Extensions.

All is working well, except that the personalization rules for the rendering aren't copied over.

I can get/set the rules on a rendering definition item without any error, but both Add-Rendering and Set-Rendering seem to ignore any rules on the rendering definition.

Example code that I've tried without success:

```
$sourceRendering = Get-Rendering -Item $Source -FinalLayout | Where-Object{$_.uniqueid -eq "{a unique id}"}
```

This works to get the rules, and the output has content:

```
 $sourceRenderingRules = $sourceRendering.Rules
```

Add the rendering to a different item:

```
Add-Rendering -Item $TargetItem -Instance $sourceRendering -PlaceHolder $sourceRendering.placeholder -FinalLayout
```

Retrieve the new rendering (it will have a new uinique ID, so get the right one in code not shown or use a different way of selecting it)

```
$CopiedRendering = Get-Rendering -Item $Target -FinalLayout | Where-Object{$_.uniqueid -eq "{a unique id}"}
```

No error, but the Rules are empty

```
$CopiedRenderingRules = $CopiedRendering.Rules
```

Copy rules to the copied rendering, no error

```
$CopiedRendering.Rules = $sourceRenderingRules
```

Copied rendering now has rules, output has content

```
$CopiedRenderingRules = $CopiedRendering.Rules
```

Update the rendering

```
Set-Rendering -Item $TargetItem -Instance $CopiedRendering -PlaceHolder $CopiedRendering.placeholder -FinalLayout
```

When I then go back and get the rendering from the target, the rules are empty.

Have I missed something? Or will I have to work with the XML in the final layout field directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wasn't able to find any way to work with the rendering rules directly in Sitecore Powershell Extensions, so I went driectly to the final renderings field and used the XML.

The end result is this function (basic, no error handling etc):

```powershell
 Function CopyRenderingRules{
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param ( 
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,position=0)]
            [Sitecore.Data.Items.Item]$SourceItem,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,position=1)]
            $SourceRenderingGUID,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,position=2)]
            [Sitecore.Data.Items.Item]$TargetItem,
            [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,position=3)]
            $TargetRenderingGUID
            )

            <# Get the rules as an XML Element #>
            [xml]$sourceRenderingsXML = New-Object -TypeName XML
            $sourceRenderingsXML.loadxml($SourceItem."__Final Renderings") 
            $sourceXpathQ = "r/d/r[@uid='$($SourceRenderingGUID)']/rls"
            $sourceRuleElement = $sourceRenderingsXML.SelectSingleNode($sourceXpathQ)


            <# Get the target rendering as an XML Element #>           
            [xml]$targetRenderingsXML = New-Object -TypeName XML
            $targetRenderingsXML.loadxml($TargetItem."__Final Renderings")
            $targetXpathQ = "r/d/r[@uid='$($TargetRenderingGUID)']"
            $TargetRendering = $targetRenderingsXML.SelectSingleNode($targetXpathQ)

            <#Append the rules element to the target rendering element  #>         
            $TargetRendering.AppendChild($targetRenderingsXML.ImportNode($sourceRuleElement,$true)) > $null

            <# Output the Renderings XML to the final renderings field on the target #>          
            $TargetItem.Editing.BeginEdit()
            $TargetItem."__Final Renderings" = $targetRenderingsXML.OuterXML
            $TargetItem.Editing.EndEdit() > $null

    }
```