# Powershell script to update personalization rule

Tags: powershell-extensions, personalization, powershell

I want to update personalization rule for all the pages which have one common rendering.

Is it possible using powershell we can identify the rendering and update personalization rule to target page and subpages.

Thankyou.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for - https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/18846/how-can-i-copy-personalization-rules-to-a-rendering-in-sitecore-powershell

Comment: No, I have gone through that post, My requirement here is I just need to update the personalization rule from target item to source and child if that rendering is already available.